# Python bash magic: passing os.environ string argument with whitespace

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I have a function that requires a path string as argument that I want to call via bash magic from a jupyter notebook.

The path string contains a whitespace. When I pass the path string directly to the bash command, it works fine. However, when I set an os.environ variable, it gets truncated at the whitespace.

```
os.environ["DATA_PATH"] = "/content/drive/My Drive/data/"

%%bash
python -m my_function --filepath "/content/drive/My Drive/data/"
Recieved string: /content/drive/My Drive/data/

python -m my_function --filepath ${DATA_PATH} 
Recieved string: /content/drive/My
```

The strange thing is that when I echo both commands, I get the same results.

```
%%bash
echo python -m my_function --filepath "/content/drive/My Drive/data/" 
echo python -m my_function --filepath ${DATA_PATH} 

python -m my_function --filepath /content/drive/My Drive/data/
python -m my_function --filepath /content/drive/My Drive/data/
```

I have tried various things like escaping the whitespace, the quotes, etc. but I can't get it to work with the os.environ variable. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quoting the variable substitution should do the trick:

```
python -m my_function --filepath "${DATA_PATH}"
```

It is a question of how bash interpolates strings. There is a rather comprehensive answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767).

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! And also thanks for the link, interesting read.